# Continuity of the Stone-Weierstrass approximation operator

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, approximation-theory

Given a family of real-valued curved $f(x;\theta)$, say for example,
$$
 f(x,\theta) = e ^ {\theta x}, x \in [-1, 1],
$$

the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem says that 
any member in the family of curve can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial $p$
$$
 \| f(x;\theta) - p(x;\theta) \|_\infty < \epsilon.
$$

To formulate the question assume that the degree of the polynomial is $n$,
so that the polynomial can be written as
$$
 p(x;\theta) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{\theta, i} x ^ i,
$$
So the approximation operator $A$ maps a curve to a polynomial
$$
 A: f(x;\theta) \mapsto p(x;\theta)
$$

Can you point to some reference that discuss the continuity of the approximation operator?
In the sense that a small change in $\theta$, should produce a small change in the coefficient $a_{\theta,i}$ of the approximating polynomial.

I known that by using the proof of the Weierstrass approximation that relies on Bernstein polynomial, the continuity of the operator can be prooved. I guess this is routinely prooved in approximation theory book, but I couldn't find a reference that treat this.

Comment: As it stands "the approximation operator" is not well defined.  There is not just a single polynomial that uniformly approximates $f$ to within $\epsilon$; there are infinitely many.

Comment: If $g \in C([-1,1])$ then let $g_\epsilon(x) =\frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-1}^1 g(t) e^{-(t-x)^2/ \epsilon^2} dt$. Note that $g_\epsilon(x)$ is analytic, approximate it by its Taylor polynomials, and show that the approximation depends on $\sup_x |g(x)-g(x+\epsilon)|$. So if your family of functions $\in C([-1,1])$ is uniformly continuous, then you can approximate it uniformly by a sequence of polynomial approximation operator.

Comment: @user1952009 It's probably a mistranslation, the family needs to be _equicontinuous_, not uniformly continuous.